# Dynamically Filling AutoCompleteTextView Suggestions

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview

I have created an `AsyncTask` to fetch suggestions from a URL every time there is a change on an `AutoCompleteTextView`. It should work fine, I don't know what the problem is.

**Fragment (with AutoCompleteTextView):**

```
atv = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.atvMovieName);
// adding event listeners for text on the auto complete text view
atv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         SuggestionFetcher fetcher = new SuggestionFetcher(getActivity(), atv);
         String title = s.toString().replace(" ", "%20");
         try {
             URL url = new URL("http://imdbapi.com/?s=" + title + "&r=xml");
             fetcher.execute(url);
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

**SuggestionFetcher:**

```
// suggestion titles will be saved here
private Stack<String> suggestions;

// this is the auto complete text view we will be handling
private AutoCompleteTextView atv;
// and it's adapter
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// context of the activity or fragment
private Context context;

private static final String TAG = "Suggestion Fetcher";

public SuggestionFetcher(Context c, AutoCompleteTextView atv) {
    this.atv = atv;
    this.context = c;
    this.suggestions = new Stack<String>();
}

@Override
protected Stack<String> doInBackground(URL... params) {
    // get the data...
    this.suggestions.add(title);

    return this.suggestions;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Stack<String> strings) {
    super.onPostExecute(strings);
    Log.v(TAG, "finished with the data: " + strings); // works, shows the results I wanted
    // update the list view
    this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
    this.atv.setAdapter(this.adapter);
}
```

As I wrote in the comments, it actually gets the data, but I get no suggestions.

Comment: just follow my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task to implement and for that I used a hidden listview below the edittext(where i enter the url or search term) and the listview will be populated from the api on the basis of change in editext using textwatcher.Try this if you need another solution.